# How to play sound when user taps on UITabBarController tab

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my application I have a uitabbar contoller for managing the three view controllers. now I want to add the sound if the user clicked any one of the tab. Source code:

```
// Declare all three view controllers
nextview *con = [[nextview alloc]init];
nextview1 *con1= [[nextview1 alloc] init];
nextview2 *con2 = [[nextview2 alloc] init]; 
//declare tab barcontroller  
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

// Set each tab to show an appropriate view controller
[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:con,con1,con2, nil]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the delegate of the `UITabBarController` and use `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` (info [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate)) to play your sound. Playing a sound on iOS is somewhat tricky, but Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

track the tabbar button in delegate - tabBarController:didSelectViewController:

and play sound with AVAudioPlayer .. code here -

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog([error description]);
    else
        [audioPlayer play];
```